# Unable to update the association field

Tags: java, odata, sap-fiori, cds

### Unable to update the association field:

### CDS Entity 1:

entity PackagingIssues : cuid, managed {

```
PackagingIssueId  :  String;
issueDes          :  String(80);
postingDocument   :  PostingDocument;
}
```

### CDS Entity 2:

entity PostingDocuments : cuid,managed {

```
PostingDocumentName  :  String;
packagingIssue      : Association to many PackagingIssues on 
packagingIssue.postingDocument = $self;
```

}

I have above two entity, i am trying to modify "packagingIssue", which is a Association of "one-many".

1)when trying **to add new PackagingIssue to the list** and running Update query, then getting  below error

2023-09-14 17:36:32.155  INFO 24764 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.s.c.a.o.v4.processors.CdsProcessor     : Exception marked the ChangeSet 10 as cancelled: Invalid CQN: UPSERT entity 'com.sap.di.irp.packagingIssue.PackagingIssues' via association 'com.sap.di.irp.postingDocument.PostingDocuments.packagingIssue' is not allowed. **The association does not cascade insert or update**. (service 'PersistenceService$Default', event 'UPDATE', entity 'com.sap.di.irp.postingDocument.PostingDocuments')

2)when trying to **remove existing object from list** and running Update query, then getting below error

2023-09-13 17:57:09.198  INFO 23132 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.s.c.a.o.v4.processors.CdsProcessor     : Exception marked the ChangeSet 44 as cancelled: Invalid CQN: UPDATE entity 'com.sap.di.irp.packagingIssue.PackagingIssues' via association 'com.sap.di.irp.postingDocument.PostingDocuments.packagingIssue' is not allowed. **The association does not cascade update.** (service 'PersistenceService$Default', event 'UPDATE', entity 'com.sap.di.irp.postingDocument.PostingDocuments')

3)when trying **to make existing list null** and running Update query, then getting below error

Error:
on marked the ChangeSet 2 as cancelled: Invalid CQN: **Value for to-many associatio**n 'com.sap.di.irp.postingDocument.PostingDocuments.packagingIssue' **must not be null. **(service 'PersistenceService$Default', event 'UPDATE', entity 'com.sap.di.irp.postingDocument.PostingDocuments')

Please don’t hesitate to share your thoughts.

Expecting better solution to update association field

Answer (score 0):

please check out here https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/guides/providing-services#%E2%80%93-deep-insert , I guess you need a deep insert here if I understand you correctly. Then you need composition rather than association.

*Note that Associations and Compositions are handled differently in (deep) inserts and updates:
Compositions → runtime deeply creates or updates entries in target entities
Associations → runtime fills in foreign keys to existing target entries*